# Add arraylist into arraylist in second attempt add duplicate the data

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I try to run this code, there are 2 arraylist, **answerList and questionList** that I set globally. first I add data to **Answer** Object and than put it in answerList after that I put that answerList into Question Object. and at last I put that Question Object into questionList. At first add the questionList become like this :

```
[
    {
        "mAnswers":[
            {
                "**mChoiceId":1**
            }
        ],
        "mQuestionId":4
    }
]
```

And then I add new data into questionList and this is the result :

```
[
    {
        "mAnswers":[
             {
                "**mChoiceId":5**
             }
        ],
        "mQuestionId":4
    },
    {
        "mAnswers":[
            {
                "**mChoiceId":5**
            }
        ],
        "mQuestionId":5
    }
]
```

as you can see, the first mChoiceId is 1 with questionId is 4, after I add new array the first mChoiceId got updated with the value of second mChoiceId. What I want when I add new array is the first mChoiceId still 1 and not get updated by the new mChoiceId that i just added

```
public void onClick(int position, Choice question) {

if (questionList.size() == 0) {


        insertAnswerToQuestion(question.getQuestionId(),question.getChoiceId());


    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < questionList.size(); j++) {

            if (checkIfQuestionIdSend(questionList.get(j).getmQuestionId(), question.getQuestionId())) {
                questionList.get(j).getmAnswers().get(0).setmChoiceId(question.getChoiceId());
                isHasSameQuestionId = true;
            } else {
                if (j == questionList.size() - 1) {
                    if (!isHasSameQuestionId) {
                        insertAnswerToQuestion(question.getQuestionId(),question.getChoiceId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    isHasSameQuestionId = false;
}
private void insertAnswerToQuestion(int QuestionId, int ChoiceId){
    answerList.clear();

    Answer answer = new Answer();
    answer.setmChoiceId(ChoiceId);

    answerList.add(answer);
    asia.popbox.app.V2.Network.BodyApiReq.FreeGiftAnswerPostBody.Question quest = new asia.popbox.app.V2.Network.BodyApiReq.FreeGiftAnswerPostBody.Question();

    quest.setmAnswers(answerList);
    quest.setmQuestionId(QuestionId);
    questionList.add(quest);

}
```

This is the question class :

```
package asia.popbox.app.V2.Network.BodyApiReq.FreeGiftAnswerPostBody;

import java.util.List;

public class Question {

private List<Answer> mAnswers;
private int mQuestionId;

public Question(List<Answer> mAnswers, int mQuestionId) {
    this.mAnswers = mAnswers;
    this.mQuestionId = mQuestionId;
}
public Question() {

}

public List<Answer> getmAnswers() {
    return mAnswers;
}

public void setmAnswers(List<Answer> mAnswers) {
    this.mAnswers = mAnswers;
}

public int getmQuestionId() {
    return mQuestionId;
}

public void setmQuestionId(int mQuestionId) {
    this.mQuestionId = mQuestionId;
}
```

}

This is Answer Class :

```
package asia.popbox.app.V2.Network.BodyApiReq.FreeGiftAnswerPostBody;



public class Answer {

private int mChoiceId;

public int getmChoiceId() {
    return mChoiceId;
}

public void setmChoiceId(int mChoiceId) {
    this.mChoiceId = mChoiceId;
}
public Answer( ) {
}
public Answer(int mChoiceId) {
    this.mChoiceId = mChoiceId;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post this class: asia.popbox.app.V2.Network.BodyApiReq.FreeGiftAnswerPostBody.Question

Comment: already edit it and add the Answer and Question class @CaoMinhVu